# ASP.NET Core cookie time expiration validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I set cookie expiration time to 120 seconds, but after this time passed, I'm still authorized in system. Does ASP.NET Core authentication middleware actually validate if a cookie is expired?

So this is piece of code how I configured it in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);    
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["InteractiveServiceSettings:AuthorityUrl"];
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["InteractiveServiceSettings:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["InteractiveServiceSettings:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("ExtrenalAPI.read");

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    }
);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

And this is simple controller, as I said after 120 seconds, I'm still able to make request through `ShopsController`, beside it has `Authorize` attribute. After 120 seconds, I would have expected to be redirected to the login page.

```
[Authorize]
public class ShopsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(shops);
    }
}
```

Also, I registered a client for this API in Identity Server (which is a standalone project) and it looks like this. It may provide you with some information.

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new[]
    {       
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("mvc1".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5446/signin-oidc" },
            FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5446/signout-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5446/signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "ExtrenalAPI.read" }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please confirm that you verified that indeed there is no silent re-authorization happening and indeed page sends back the cookie. You probably also want to confirm that initial cookie send with correct expiration date... (Use Dev tools in browser or any HTTP debugger like Fiddler for that).

Comment: There is only controller with Authorize attribute marked, also I have not any custom middleware or filter, I'm unsure where silent re-authorization can occur

Comment: Well based on your scenario and description, please check your servver time and make sure that the server time is accurate. If the server time is not correct, it may affect the expiration calculations.
Because if the client and server machines are out of sync, it could lead to unexpected behavior.
In addition, try in private browser mode, sometimes, cache or cookie expiration time can cause the issue as well.

Comment: Server time is not an issue. I am testing it on my local machine and also tried incognito mode, but the result is the same. Still haven't figured out what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

There is a property `SlidingExpiration` that is by default set to `true` which re-issues the cookie, if the request is done less than half of the time before expiring.

To prevent this behaviour you might want to change your settings to `false`.

Related info:

[CookieAuthenticationOptions.SlidingExpiration Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I swear I did not make any requests during this 120 seconds. Even setting SlidingExpiration to false, the result is the same as before and still authorized.

Comment: Then it might be that OpenID challenge is happening which re-issues the ticket. Maybe the setup needs to be there differently.

Comment: I added some extra information to this ticket, it might tell you something.

Comment: Well. Unfortunately, it doesn't give much more to work with. If I were you I would use [CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.events?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to debug what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue and adjusted ExpiresUtc to 120 seconds and IsPersistent to true in AuthenticationProperties during logging in to the system. It is discussed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0#absolute-cookie-expiration

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(120)
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);
```

But I am currently pondering another question. What is the purpose of setting the ExpireTimeSpan to 120 seconds while adding cookie authentication as I stated in my initial post?